# What is the maximal intersection area?

Tags: geometry

> A triangle and square that are regular with side lengths of $6$ and $5$, respectively, are drawn. What is the largest possible intersection of the two polygons?

I asked a similar question to this earlier, but people were confused about if I meant regular or something else. I adjusted the question, and I think it is more interesting now. If anyone has any ideas for the, please try. I have come up with a few different arrangements that I think yield a large area, but I can't prove they are the largest.

Comment: A triangle with side lengths 6 is always equilateral (hence regular). And a square is by definition a regular quadrilateral. The problem earlier was with the hexagon. You can have a hexagon all of whose sides are the same, but  which isn't regular because it has funny angles.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Given a square of side $s$ and an equilateral triangle of side $t$.
Let $\rho = \frac{t}{s}$.  one can show:

> When $\rho > \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, in the search of a configuration which maximizes the overlapping area, one can limit the search to those configurations where the triangle and square is sharing a sideline.

Accepting this claim, it will become a simple exercise in calculus to show maximum overlapping occurs when the midpoint of an edge of triangle coincides with the midpoint of an edge of the square. The maximum overlapping area will be given by the formula:

$$s^2 \times \begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left[\rho^2 - (\rho-1)^2 - (\rho - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}})^2\right], & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \le \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\\1, & \rho \ge \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+1\end{cases}$$

For the problem at hand where $(s,t) = (5,6)$, the maximum overlapping area equals to
$30 - \frac{103}{4\sqrt{3}} \sim 15.13323056836714$

For a rigorous justification of above claim, it will be really tedious. I will attempt to provide an outline below.

**Long answer**

We will identify euclidean plane with complex plane. For any point with coordinate $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we will treat the number $z = x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$ as its "complex" coordinate.

Let $\theta_0 = 15^\circ = \frac{\pi}{12}$. Let $S$ be the unit square $[0,1]^2$ and $T$ be an equilateral triangle with side $\rho$ and vertices at complex coordinates $0$, $\rho$ and $\rho e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$. 
For any isometry $g \in E(2) {}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$, let

1. $gT = \{ g(p) : p \in T \}\quad$ be the image of $T$ under $g$.
2. $\lambda(g) = \verb/Area/(S \cap gT)\quad$ be the overlapping area between $S$ and $gT$.
3. $\Lambda(\rho) = \sup\limits_{g \in E(2)} \lambda(g)\quad$ be the supremum of possible overlapping areas.

There are two trivial cases:

- For $\rho \le \frac{1}{\cos\theta_0}$, $gT \subset S$ for rotation  $g : z \mapsto e^{i\theta_0} z$. We have $\Lambda(\rho) = \verb/Area/(T) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\rho^2$.
- For $\rho \ge \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} + 1$, $S \subset gT$ for translation $g : z \mapsto z + \frac{1-\rho}{2}$. We find $\Lambda(\rho) = \verb/Area/(S) = 1$.

In following discussion, we will assume $\frac{1}{\cos\theta_0} < \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} + 1$.

Notice $S$ is invariant under reflection with respect to line $y = \frac12$. Since $E(2)$ is generated by this reflection and $SE(2){}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$, in definition of $\Lambda(\rho)$, we can replace $E(2)$ by $SE(2)$.

In terms of complex coordinate $z$, isometries in $SE(2)$ are map of the form $z \mapsto \alpha z + \beta$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\alpha| = 1$. This allows us to identity $SE(2)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and hence a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$$SE(2)\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2 = \big\{ (\alpha,\beta ) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 : |\alpha| = 1\big\} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$$
Under this identification, $\lambda(g)$ is a continuous function on $SE(2)$. Furthermore, its support
$$X \stackrel{def}{=} \verb/Supp/(\lambda) = \{ g \in SE(2) : \lambda(g) \ge 0 \}$$
is a closed subset of $S^1 \times \bar{B}(0,\rho) =
\big\{ (\alpha,\beta ) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 : |\alpha| = 1, |\beta| \le \rho \big\}$ and hence is compact. This implies $\lambda(g)$ attains its supremum at some $g_{max} \in X$. In the definition of $\Lambda(\rho)$, we can replace the supremum by a maximum. i.e.

$$\Lambda(\rho) = \sup_{g\in SE(2)}\lambda(g) = \max_{g\in SE(2)} \lambda(g) = \max_{g\in X}\lambda(g) = \lambda(g_{max})$$

The problem at hand is equivalent to computing the value of $5^2\Lambda\left(\frac65\right)$. This is essentially a problem of determining the possible location of $g_{max}$.

Let $Y$ be the set of those $g \in SE(2)$ where $\partial S$ and $\partial(gT)$ intersect non trivially. More precisely, those $g$ such that the intersection of an edge of $S$ and an edge of $T$ is a line segment of non-zero length. It is not hard to verify $\lambda(g)$ is differentiable unless $g \in Y$. In order for any $g \notin Y$ to maximize $\lambda(g)$, it need to satisfy $d\lambda|_{g} = 0$. i.e. the $1$-form $d\lambda$ vanishes at $g$.

Let $g \in X \setminus Y$. Notice $SE(2)$ consists of translations/rotations of the plane and translations can be generated by rotations arond different centers. We only need to figure out what happens to $\lambda(g)$ when we perturb $g$ by infinitesimal rotations.

Let $R_\theta$ be the rotation $z \mapsto z_0 + e^{i\theta} (z - z_0)$ with respect to center $z_0$. For small $\theta$, $R_\theta g \in X \setminus Y$ and $S \cap \partial(R_\theta gT)$ is a finite union of polylines. Let
$\mathcal{E}_\theta$ be the collection of their endpoints.
For each endpoint $p$, assign a number $\epsilon_p = \pm 1$ depends on whether a polyline leaves/enters $S$ at $p$. One can show that

$$\left.\frac{d}{d\theta}\lambda(R_\theta g)\right|_{\theta=0} = -\frac12 \sum_{p \in \mathcal{E}_0}\epsilon_p|p - z_0|^2$$

In order for $d\lambda|_{g}$ to vanish, the necessary and sufficient condition is

$$\sum_{p\in \mathcal{E}_0} \epsilon_p |p-z_0|^2 = 0, \forall z_0
\quad\iff\quad \bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 1em]{\sum_{p \in \mathcal{E}_0} \epsilon_p |p|^2 = \sum_{p \in \mathcal{E}_0} \epsilon_p p = 0}$$

The two conditions on RHS pose very severe constraint of what $gT$ could be.

For the $3$ line segments obtained by intersecting $S$ with the $3$ edges of $gT$. They need to have same length and their perpendicular bisectors need to be concurrent.

For the intersection of $gT$ with the $4$ edges of $S$, we either get 
$2$ line segments on a pair of opposite edges of $S$ or $4$ line segments, one for each edge of $S$.

In the first case, the line segments on opposite edge of $S$ have same length and their perpendicular bisectors coincides. This forces an edge of the triangle parallel to an edge of the square. By a translation, we can find a $g' \in Y$ with $\lambda(g') = \lambda(g)$. In the search of $g_{max}$, we can ignore this sort of $g \in X\setminus Y$.

For the second case, up to rotation, it is essentially what illustrated below

[image: square/triangle intersection]

This sort of configurations can be parameterized by two parameters $(\ell,\theta)$ with $\theta \in (-\theta_0,\theta_0)$. In terms of them,
we have:

- $\theta_1 = \theta_0 + \theta$, $\theta_2 = \theta_0 - \theta$ and $\theta_3 = \frac{\pi}{4} - \theta$.
- $|HI| = |JK| = |LM| = \ell$.
- $|AH| = |KL| = 1 - \ell \cos\theta_1$.
- $|AM| = |IJ| = 1 - \ell \cos\theta_2$.

Apply sine rule to $\triangle FJI$ and $\triangle LKG$, we find
$$|FJ| = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(1 - \ell\cos\theta_2)\cos\theta_1 \quad\text{ and }\quad |KG| = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(1 - \ell\cos\theta_1)\cos\theta_2$$
This leads to
$$\rho = |FG| 
= |FJ| + |JK| + |KG|
= \ell + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(\cos\theta_1 + \cos\theta_2 - 2\ell\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2)$$
which can be simplified to 
$$\rho = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(2\cos\theta_0 \cos\theta - \ell\cos(2\theta))
\quad\iff\quad
\ell = \frac{1}{\cos(2\theta)}\left(2\cos\theta_0\cos\theta - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho\right)
$$

This means given $\rho$, we only need $\theta$ to specify a candidate for $g_{max}$. Let $g_{\theta}$ be such a candidate. We have

$$\begin{align}\lambda(g_{\theta}) &= \verb/Area/(AHIJKLM)
= 1 - \verb/Area/(HBI) - \verb/Area/(JCK) - \verb/Area/(LDJ)\\
&= 1 - \frac{\ell^2}{4}\left(\sin(2\theta_1) + \sin(2\theta_3) + \sin(2\theta_2)\right)\end{align}$$
This can be simplified to
$$\lambda(g_{\theta})
= 1 - \frac{\ell^2}{2}\cos(2\theta)
= 1 - \frac{1}{2\cos(2\theta)}\left(2\cos\theta_0\cos\theta - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho\right)^2$$

In order for $d\lambda|_{g_\theta} = 0$ at a specific $\theta'$,  we need $\frac{d}{d\theta}\lambda(g_\theta)|_{\theta=\theta'} = 0$. This is equivalent to

$$\frac{\sin(2\theta')}{\cos(2\theta')} = 
\frac{2\cos\theta_0\sin\theta'}{2\cos\theta_0\cos\theta' - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho}
\quad\iff\quad \sin\theta'(\cos\theta_0 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho\cos\theta') = 0
$$
Since $\theta' = 0$ is a root of RHS, $\theta = 0$ is always a local extremum of $\lambda(g_\theta)$.

In order for other non-zero $\theta' \in (-\theta_0,\theta_0)$ to be a local extremum, we need

$$\begin{align} 1 > \cos\theta' > \cos\theta_0
\implies & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \rho > \cos\theta_0 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho\cos\theta' > \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho\cos\theta_0\\
\implies & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} > \rho > \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta_0
\end{align}
$$
This means for $\rho \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}{\cos\theta_0}$ or $\ge \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, $\theta = 0$ is the only local extremum.

By plotting the function $\lambda(g_\theta)$ for various $\rho$. One find
the local extremum at $\theta = 0$ is a local maximum for $\rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta_0$. For $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta_0 < \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, the local extremum at $\theta = 0$ turns into a local minimum. The local maximum moved to $\theta' = \pm \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cos\theta_0}{\sqrt{3}\rho}\right)$.

By comparing the values $\lambda(g)$ for $g \in Y$, we find these two types of local maximum are global maximum for $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta_0 < \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. The end result is

$$\bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 1em]{\Lambda(\rho) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\rho^2, & \rho < \frac{1}{\cos\theta_0}\\
1 - \frac12\left(2\cos\theta_0 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\rho\right)^2,& \frac{1}{\cos\theta_0} \le \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta_0\\
\sin^2\theta_0 + \frac38 \rho^2, & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta_0 \le \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left[\rho^2 - (\rho-1)^2 - (\rho - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}})^2\right],& \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \le \rho < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+1\\
1, & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+1 \le \rho
\end{cases}
}$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - $E(2)$ is the [Euclidean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group) of two dimensions. It consists of isometries (translations/rotations/reflections) of the plane.
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - $SE(2)$ is subgroup of $E(2)$ consists of direct 
  isometries (translations/rotations) of the plane.